# VBA How do I conditionally format a range of cells based on the value of one cell in that range?

Tags: excel, vba, string, formula, conditional-formatting

My goal is to have the text of the entire row turn grey if the value of a particular cell in that row shows "GAT1". I can do this fine with regular conditional formatting but am struggling to figure out how to automate the creation of this formatting with a macro.

My problem really comes down to the fact that the criteria for my formatting uses a formula to specify the text string. My understanding is that I usually have to put text strings in quotes or VBA will not recognize them as such, however the syntax of VBA will not allow me to put the said text string in quotes as the formula containing this string is already enclosed in quotes itself. (e.g. I was trying to write my condition as such - Formula1:="=F1="GAT1"" or Formula1:="=F1=GAT1" but neither of these options produces the desired result)

The code below is my most recent attempt. I've tried separating out the text string and concatenating it together but this hasn't worked.

```
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range("A1:P200")
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$F1" & "=GAT1"
        With MyRange.FormatConditions(1)
            .Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        End With
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range("A1:P200")
With MyRange.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$F1=""GAT1""")
    .Font.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
End With
```

Comment: So this works in isolation, however I'm running into a new problem. I have other conditional formatting statements for various ranges on the same sheet that I have in my code. They all come before I want to use this piece of code. Before these lines of code are executed, all of the conditional formatting that I've set up via previous lines of code is as it should be. However, when these lines execute, it changes the ranges of the other conditional statements that I have created. Any idea why it would do this?

Comment: For further clarification, If I change the code to only change the font of the cells in column F (the same column with the cells that have "GAT1") I don't run into any problems. It's when I try to expand this range to encompass the orw of cells that I run into problems.

Comment: Can you update your question to include enough code to replicate the problem?